# The site is not enabled for registration error, while self registration for community from force.com site

Tags: force.com, customer-community

I've created a force.com site, From force.com site public user can able to register/login. For that I'm using community.

I've put the **CommunitiesSelfReg** page in my force.com site and try to register it shows me error like

> The site is not enabled for registration.

I've configured the login setting of community. Please check screenshot

[image]

also Configure the apex class as below;

[image]

Comment: you can check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97051/creating-community-user-through-apex

Comment: also this. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53371/customer-portal-self-registration-for-new-users

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162709/is-is-posible-to-self-register-as-a-community-user-in-the-dev-org/162712

Comment: @SantanuBoral Force.com site shows the login not allowd, I'm unable to edit.

Comment: have you followed all the steps here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: @glls. Yes I've followed same steps